# jQuery change parent div radio input with different background

Tags: jquery, css, forms, radio-button

Within a form, I have inserted four radio inputs; the code is as follows:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#checkact1").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('#ck01').addClass('st1_bk_color');
      $('#ck02').removeClass('st2_bk_color');
      $('#ck03').removeClass('st3_bk_color');
      $('#ck04').removeClass('st4_bk_color');
    }
  });
  $("#checkact2").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('#ck01').removeClass('st1_bk_color');
      $('#ck01').addClass('st0_bk_color');
      $('#ck02').addClass('st2_bk_color');
      $('#ck03').removeClass('st3_bk_color');
      $('#ck04').removeClass('st4_bk_color');
    }
  });
  $("#checkact3").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('#ck01').removeClass('st1_bk_color');
      $('#ck01').addClass('st0_bk_color');
      $('#ck02').removeClass('st2_bk_color');
      $('#ck03').addClass('st3_bk_color');
      $('#ck04').removeClass('st4_bk_color');
    }
  });
  $("#checkact4").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('#ck01').removeClass('st1_bk_color');
      $('#ck01').addClass('st0_bk_color');
      $('#ck02').removeClass('st2_bk_color');
      $('#ck03').removeClass('st3_bk_color');
      $('#ck04').addClass('st4_bk_color');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#form .col:nth-child(1) input[type="radio"]:checked,
#form .col:nth-child(2) input[type="radio"]:checked,
#form .col:nth-child(3) input[type="radio"]:checked,
#form .col:nth-child(4) input[type="radio"]:checked {
  border-color: #FF1493;
  background-color: #FF1493;
  box-shadow: none;
}

#form .col:nth-child(1) input[type="radio"]:checked+label,
#form .col:nth-child(1) input[type="radio"]:checked+label span,
#form .col:nth-child(2) input[type="radio"]:checked+label,
#form .col:nth-child(2) input[type="radio"]:checked+label span,
#form .col:nth-child(3) input[type="radio"]:checked+label,
#form .col:nth-child(3) input[type="radio"]:checked+label span,
#form .col:nth-child(4) input[type="radio"]:checked+label,
#form .col:nth-child(4) input[type="radio"]:checked+label span {
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
}

.st0_bk_color {
  background-color: #f5f8fa !important;
}

.st1_bk_color {
  background-color: #7e8299 !important;
}

.st2_bk_color {
  background-color: #20c997 !important;
}

.st3_bk_color {
  background-color: #7239ea !important;
}

.st4_bk_color {
  background-color: #fd7e14 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <div class="col">
    <div id="ck01">
      <input type="radio" name="checkact" id="checkact1" value="option1" checked>
      <label for="checkact1"> Lorem <br> <span>Ipsum</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div id="ck02">
      <input type="radio" name="checkact" id="checkact2" value="option2" checked>
      <label for="checkact2"> Lorem <br> <span>Ipsum</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div id="ck03">
      <input type="radio" name="checkact" id="checkact3" value="option3" checked>
      <label for="checkact3"> Lorem <br> <span>Ipsum</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div id="ck04">
      <input type="radio" name="checkact" id="checkact4" value="option4" checked>
      <label for="checkact4"> Lorem <br> <span>Ipsum</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

How can I write it better and optimize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ){
    $("input[id^=checkact]").click(function() {
      var n = $(this).attr("id").replace("checkact","");
      $('div[id^=ck]').removeClass("st1_bk_color st2_bk_color st3_bk_color st4_bk_color")
      $('#ck' + ('0' + n).slice(-2)).addClass(`st${n}_bk_color`);
    }).filter(":checked").trigger("click")
});
```

Main thing is that I use the `id^=` selector, that means it will select all elements where the id start with what is defined after ^=. like : `id^=checkact`

**Demo**

```js
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ){
    $("input[id^=checkact]").click(function() {
      var n = $(this).attr("id").replace("checkact","");
      $('div[id^=ck]').removeClass("st1_bk_color st2_bk_color st3_bk_color st4_bk_color")
      $('#ck' + ('0' + n).slice(-2)).addClass(`st${n}_bk_color`);
    }).filter(":checked").trigger("click")
});
```

```css
#form .col:nth-child(1) input[type="radio"]:checked,
#form .col:nth-child(2) input[type="radio"]:checked,
#form .col:nth-child(3) input[type="radio"]:checked,
#form .col:nth-child(4) input[type="radio"]:checked {
    border-color: #FF1493;
    background-color: #FF1493;
    box-shadow: none;
}
#form .col:nth-child(1) input[type="radio"]:checked + label,
#form .col:nth-child(1) input[type="radio"]:checked + label span,
#form .col:nth-child(2) input[type="radio"]:checked + label,
#form .col:nth-child(2) input[type="radio"]:checked + label span,
#form .col:nth-child(3) input[type="radio"]:checked + label,
#form .col:nth-child(3) input[type="radio"]:checked + label span,
#form .col:nth-child(4) input[type="radio"]:checked + label,
#form .col:nth-child(4) input[type="radio"]:checked + label span {
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
.st0_bk_color {
    background-color: #f5f8fa !important;
}
.st1_bk_color {
    background-color: #7e8299 !important;
}
.st2_bk_color {
    background-color: #20c997 !important;
}
.st3_bk_color {
    background-color: #7239ea !important;
}
.st4_bk_color {
    background-color: #fd7e14 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <div class="col">
    <div id="ck01">
      <input type="radio" name="checkact" id="checkact1" value="option1" checked>
      <label for="checkact1"> Lorem <br> <span>Ipsum</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div id="ck02">
      <input type="radio" name="checkact" id="checkact2" value="option2" >
      <label for="checkact2"> Lorem <br> <span>Ipsum</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div id="ck03">
      <input type="radio" name="checkact" id="checkact3" value="option3" >
      <label for="checkact3"> Lorem <br> <span>Ipsum</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div id="ck04">
      <input type="radio" name="checkact" id="checkact4" value="option4" >
      <label for="checkact4"> Lorem <br> <span>Ipsum</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>        
</form>
```

Comment: Wow, greta and thanks!
However, there is still a small problem.
The first radio input is checked by default, so it already uses the custom background. You have to bring it back to the state of others when it is no longer checked.

Comment: @redblade well one problem is that you have `checked` on all the input. but you can add `.filter(":checked").trigger("click")` to the code. Look at the demo

Comment: Ok. In your demo the initial state is radio 4. I have to use the first radio.
What is the instruction in your code that makes me change this?

Comment: @redblade I don't follow you, you want the first radio to be default checked?

Comment: Yes, sure and sorry if I don't explain myself well.

Comment: @redblade Look at my demo. You should only have one `checked` attribute. Now the first radio has that.